# ISerializable and JsonObject/JsonProperty JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

We have objects which rely on both the ISerializable (to mark the interfaces as serializable for implementers) and internally there are also JsonObject and JsonProperty attributes. As an example:

```
[JsonObject("Example")]
[Serializable]
public class Example : ISerializable
{
    [JsonProperty("TEST")]
    string _testString;

    public string TestString
    {
        get => _testString;
        set => _testString = value;
    }

    protected Example(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (info == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(info), $"{nameof(info)} is null.");
        }

        _testString = info.GetString(nameof(TestString));
    }

    protected virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue(nameof(TestString), _testString);
    }

    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (info == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(info), $"{nameof(info)} is null.");
        }

        GetObjectData(info, context);
    }
}
```

So is there a way to enforce the Json serializer to use either the ISerializable interface or the attributes. If there is no option to enforce, perhaps there is the option to prioritize the different mechanisms?

**Update**

Based on one comment below I added a contract resolver but this leads to wrong/missing content in my serialized string - I guess I use the contract resolver in a wrong way?

```
public class ContractResolver : IContractResolver
{
    public JsonContract ResolveContract(Type type)
    {
        if(typeof(ISerializable).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            return new JsonISerializableContract(type);
        }
        return new JsonObjectContract(type);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly clear how `ISerializable` (assuming https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810974/what-is-the-point-of-the-iserializable-interface) is related to text serialization....

Comment: It is not related to text serialization. It just means the object can be serialized - and I think that's also the reason why this interface was supported in JSON.NET. So I do not really understand your comment?

Comment: Why do you need both ways? Do you want to serialize the object differently based on the chosen option?

Comment: @PeterCsala: Exactly this is what I want to achieve.

Comment: I think you need to implement a custom Contract Resolver and override the `CreateContract` method. In case of  `ISerializable` you need to use `JsonISerializableContract` otherwise `JsonObjectContract`.

Comment: @PeterCsala: I think this is the right direction. I updated my question above with a sample implementation but now some of my data is missing in the serialized text but unwanted parts appear. I think I misunderstood the usage of "CreateContract"?

Comment: if you simply want to disable use of `ISerializable` across the board set [`DefaultContractResolver.IgnoreSerializableInterface = true`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_IgnoreSerializableInterface.htm) as shown in [JSON.NET is ignoring properties in types derived from System.Exception. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27197432/3744182).  Is that enough, or do you need to selectively ignore `ISerializable` only for specific types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create custom logic you would need to create your `IContractResolver` by deriving it from `DefaultContractResolver`.  Then override the protected `CreateContract` method instead of `ResolveContract`.

For example, the following resolver will prioritize `ISerializable` before the `[JsonObject]` attribute (it is the other way around in the [base implementation](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs#L1189)).

```
public class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type type)
    {
        JsonContract contract = base.CreateContract(type);
        if (!IgnoreSerializableInterface &&
            typeof(ISerializable).IsAssignableFrom(type) && 
            !(contract is JsonDictionaryContract))
        {
            return CreateISerializableContract(type);
        }
        return contract;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems this is almost working. Anyway for dictionaries the output is different with the customcontractresolver compared to the default. With the customcontractresolver there is also output like "  "Version": 2,
  "Comparer": {
   "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1[[System.String, mscorlib]], mscorlib"
  },
  "HashSize": 3,"

Comment: Another small comment. Instead of calling "return new JsonISerializableContract(type);" it is better to call the "return CreateISerializableContract(type);" Otherwise it is not possible to deserialize the content.

Comment: Yes, you're right-- that was an oversight.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a fix for the dictionary issue as well.