# How can I avoid serialization of child properties of a nested class object?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, reflection, properties

I am writing a web api using my existing model classes and model services which are being used by many other applications too which needs the model to be fully exposed in serialization.  Can I use the same model object for web api and expose only few fields.

I have tried using JsonContractResolver, but it fails to serialize child properties in a nested class.

```
 /*Model class*/
  public class A
  {
    public int A1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime A2 { get; set; }
    public List<B> A3 { get; set; }
  }
  public class B
  {
    public string B1 { get; set; }
    public string B2 { get; set; }
    public string B3 { get; set; }
  }
```

Expected output:
When a web app method gets the members of class A, it should return the following JSON:

```
{"A1":1,"A2":"2017-02-10","A3":[{"B1":"test1","B2":"test2","B3":"test3"}]}
```

When the web API gets the member of class A, it should return:

```
{"A1":1,"A3":[{"B1":"test1"}]}
```

How can I adjust my code to achieve this result?

Comment: _"use the same model object for web api and expose only few fields"_ - use viewmodels, use anonymous types or [use a custom serializer per application or endpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157511/newtonsoft-add-jsonignore-at-runtime). What did your research show?

Answer (score 0):

Each domain should have its own models/classes.
The web app should have a model that exposes all of the fields and the web api should have a model that exposes only part of the field.

```
namespace X.WebApp.Models {

    public class A {
        public int A1 { get; set; }
            public DateTime A2 { get; set; }
            public List<B> A3 { get; set; }
    }

    public class B {
        public string B1 { get; set; }
            public string B2 { get; set; }
            public string B3 { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace X.WebApi.Models {

    public class A {
        public int A1 { get; set; }
            public List<B> A3 { get; set; }
    }

    public class B {
        public string B1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

These models could be built from a more general models namespace

```
namespace X.Common.Models {

    public class A {
        public int A1 { get; set; }
            public DateTime A2 { get; set; }
            public List<B> A3 { get; set; }
        // More fields...
    }

    public class B {
        public string B1 { get; set; }
            public string B2 { get; set; }
            public string B3 { get; set; }
        // More fields...
    }
}
```