# Dynamically ignore property on sealed class when serializing JSON with System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, serialization, .net-core, system.text.json

#### Question

Can I dynamically ignore a property from a sealed class using [`System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer)?

#### Example Code

**Example class from another library**:

```cs
public sealed class FrozenClass
{
    // [JsonIgnore] <- cannot apply because I don't own this class
    public int InternalId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**Default Serialization**:

```cs
var person = new FrozenClass() { InternalId = 3, FirstName = "Dorothy", LastName = "Vaughan" };
var jsonString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(person);
```

**Actual Outcome**:

```js
{ "InternalId": 3, "FirstName": "Dorothy", "LastName": "Vaughan" }
```

**Expected Outcome**:

```js
{ "FirstName": "Dorothy", "LastName": "Vaughan" }
```

#### Alternatives that don't work

There are two other questions on how to [add JsonIgnore at RunTime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25157511/1366033) & [add dynamic property name for serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50565358/1366033), but both are targeted at [Newtonsoft's Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) - and often reference [this extension method](https://blog.rsuter.com/advanced-newtonsoft-json-dynamically-rename-or-ignore-properties-without-changing-the-serialized-class/)

There are several ways to modify the way a class is serialized with the native `JsonSerializer`, but all seem to rely on modifying the underlying class:

- You can [exclude properties from serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#exclude-properties-from-serialization) by adding the [`[JsonIgnore]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute) attribute to the original class
- You can [register a JsonConverter on a property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to#registration-sample---jsonconverter-on-a-property) by adding the [`[JsonConverter]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1) attribute to the original class

However, in my case, the class is from another library and cannot be extended

#### Workarounds

A possible workaround is to create another exportable class and setup a mapper between them

```cs
public class MyFrozenClass
{
    public MyFrozenClass(FrozenClass frozen)
    {
        this.FirstName = frozen.FirstName;
        this.LastName = frozen.LastName;
    }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var jsonString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(new MyFrozenClass(person));
```

Comment: 15ish years of "quite involved with serializers" experience has taught me that *the first moment* a serializer starts fighting with what you want / what a type is: to go with a dedicated DTO, i.e. what you have in your "possible workaround". In the long run, I've found that just doing that saves a *lot* of time and pain.

Comment: You can use a [custom converter ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to) to emit JSON explicitly but this may be too much work. Mapping using eg `AutoMapper` is a lot easier and far safer - for your sanity

Comment: With Json.NET you could do this easily with a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples), however the equivalent types in `System.Text.Json` -- [`JsonClassInfo`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonClassInfo.cs) and [`JsonPropertyInfo`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonPropertyInfo.cs) -- are **internal**.

Comment: See: [System.Text.Json API is there something like IContractResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58926112/3744182).  The workarounds of a DTO or custom `JsonConverter` would seem to be the way to go.

Comment: For an example of a custom `JsonConverter<T>` that is fairly generic see [How to exclude a property from being serialized in System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize() using a JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58566735/3744182).  In fact I think your question could be a duplicate of the two questions to which I linked, agree?

Comment: @MarcGravell is right, DTO is the way. However I found using interfaces is more handy than DTO classes + Mapping. The dupe question actually has an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61344654/56621