# A decent way to dynamically return partial object in web api response?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, design-patterns

We have a web api project, which returns objects such as

```
    public class ChargesInfo
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public decimal? Amc { get; set; }
        public DateTime? AmcDate { get; set; }
        public string AnnualChargeNote { get; set; }
        .....
    }
```

We would like to allow our customers to return partial data dynamically. 
For example, they could call this: `api/returnFundInfo?fields=amc,amcdate,AnnualChargeNote`, we will just return requested fields.

What I think, is that in business logic, we still populate all fields. Then when outputting data, I can use some trick to exclude some fields (possibly `ShouldSerialize` method from newton Json)

is this sound a good plan? anyone has better design ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OData](https://www.odata.org/) that have out of the box feature [$select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/using-select-expand-and-value#using-select)

```
api/returnFundInfo?$select=amc,amcdate,AnnualChargeNote
```

or implement it manually like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45816435/4275342)

Comment: Hi, This sounds very interesting, but I don't really know enough about Odata, do you mean I don't need to write any code to return individual properties, and it is all done by underlying Microsoft code?

Comment: It depends. Choose the best way for you. Read more about OData, try to write custom ContractResolver  and then you will see what is the better approach