# How to serialize only properties which passed to constructor?

Tags: .net, json, vb.net

I have classes which I serialize to a JSON String. For that, I'm using Newtonsoft.Json

It looks like this:

```vb
<JsonObject()>
Public Class MyClass

    Private _a;
    Private _b;

    Public Sub New(ByVal an As String, ByVal b as String)
        _a = a
        _b = b
    End Sub

    Public Property a As String
        Get
            Return _a
         End Get
         Protected Set(value As String)
             _a = value
         End Set
    End Property

    Public Property b As String
        Get
            Return _b
        End Get
        Protected Set(value As String)
            _b = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

I put them in a list and serialize this:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listMyObject)
```

But sometimes I don't need every Property in my JSON String. Is it possible to serialize properties I passed to the constructor? As in this case?:

```vb
Public Sub New(ByVal an As String)
    _a = a
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the c# tag.

Comment: How can this be related to both `c#` and `vb.net` ?

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne - please note that any user is able to edit posts, including tags. Any user with 2000 or higher rep will have edits applied immediately.

Comment: I guess you want to have multiple constructor overloads, and depending on which was used when creating the object, you would only want to serialize specific properties, is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Newtonsoft json Serialize Conditional Property](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeConditionalProperty.htm).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33647007/832052) in C# demonstrates it in action.

In your case,

```vb
<JsonObject()>
Public Class MyClassName

    Public Property A As String
    Private ReadOnly _shouldSerializeA As Boolean
    Public Function ShouldSerializeA() As Boolean
        Return _shouldSerializeA
    End Function

    Public Property B As String
    Private ReadOnly _shouldSerializeB As Boolean
    Public Function ShouldSerializeB() As Boolean
        Return _shouldSerializeB
    End Function

    Public Sub New(ByVal a As String, ByVal b As String)
        Me.A = a
        Me.B = b
        Me._shouldSerializeA = True
        Me._shouldSerializeB = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal a As String)
        Me.A = a
        Me._shouldSerializeA = True
        Me._shouldSerializeB = False
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the attribute `<JsonIgnore>` over the properties you don't want to serialize