# jsonIgnore with custom condition .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I'm using System.Text.Json.Serialization; to ignore attribute on serialization with [JsonIgnore] annotation.
exemple:

```
 [JsonIgnore]
 public string Name { get; set; }
```

Is this a way to use a custom condition with [JsonIgnore]?

for example

```
     [JsonIgnore=someFunctionThatReturnsBoolean()]
     public string Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NewtonSoft add JSONIGNORE at runTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157511/newtonsoft-add-jsonignore-at-runtime)